How is manual import of product catalog mapped to IGO_ data extensions?
For now, we are manually updating our product catalogs for Einstein Recommendations in the Marketing Cloud.
If the mapping is done correctly and the update is successful, I notice that the data extensions IGO_PRODUCTS and IGO_PRODUCTATTRIBS are populated with data. For each product we get one row in IGO_PRODUCTS and for all the attributes not included in IGO_PRODUCTS we get several key/value rows in IGO_PRODUCTATTRIBS.
Due to some error, a part of the data has been deleted. The data extensions above may have been manually emptied. I have tried to re-upload the product catalog. But I get strange results.

Not all products in the CSV file appear in IGO_PRODUCTS the way they did before.
IGO_PRODUCTATTRIBS no longer contains all metadata needed. E.g., the product Url and Image links are gone and we only have values for ModifiedDate.

I am looking for a well-documented approach to re-upload the product catalogs in such circumstances. I need to know how they are populated, and how to troubleshoot. Right now, it is a bit of a black box how MC maps this data to its data extensions, and I cannot continue by simply trial and error.
I have read the following documents to no avail.

Behaviour based segmentation with Einstein
Einstein Recommendations SFMC Cookbook
Marketing Cloud Personalization Builder and Einstein Recommendations Implementation Guide Summer '24 (PDF)

Neither of these documents addresses this specific problem.
All help is appreciated!

The platform does not use these data extension in any way. I would suggest you import your catalog into a DE if you have a use case for the catalog and the data
as far as dropping the catalog you can do this in admin >> reporting >> catalogs >> drop catalog

Could you briefly explain what you mean "The platform does not use these data extension in any way"? So they are only here for us to query them? And shouldn't dropping the catalog in Reporting > Admin Tools > Catalogs not empty IGO_PRODUCTS and IGO_PRODUCTATTRIBS.

correct the DE are just for you use cases, the platform does not use these DE at all, they can be deleted and the platform would continue to work as expected, nothing removed data from these DE

My recommendation will be for you to ask Salesforce support to "wipe" the catalogue, so you can do a fresh and full re-upload. I haven's seen your issue many times before, but when I did, this solution usually did the trick.

Hi Lukas, I have created the ticket. But is there a way that one can do this alone? We have access to the data extensions. When it comes to a product catalog, is there any other data extensions except IGO_PRODUCTS and IGO_PRODUCTATTRIBS that are updated?

The issue, @Disasterkid, is that data extension are only a replica of the IGO data. The "real" system of record is outside of SFMC, and hence looking at what records are available in IGO_PRODUCTATTRIBS will not necessarily give you the accurate representation of the actual catalogue. To my knowledge deleting the catalogue is not possible in the UI.

I see! To delete the catalog, one option I have tried is to "drop" it in Email Recommendations > Reporting > Admin Tools > Catalogs > Drop Catalog. But when I did that once, nothing was deleted from the IGO_ data extensions. So, I don't know what that was for. Do you?

@Disasterkid it MIGHT have resolved it, but again - you don't have any exact way of ensuring the actual catalogue is indeed empty. This doesn't have a UI. The reason nothing was deleted from the data extension might be due to the actual overwrite/deletion only happening once a day.

Thank you for your input. Let me get into contact with SF Support, if the problem was solved, I will mark your answer.

Is there anywhere these insights are documented? E.g., that the drop catalog happens only once a day?

@Disasterkid - the documentation, especially concerning the internals of Einstein Recommendations, is quite scarce. And you have already found the most comprehensive sources (from Jörn and myself). The daily batch is only something I am guessing.

I asked SF support and they cannot do a wipe as you suggested. Everything is in AWS and we have no access to it.
